# Opening file from python

Tags: python, command-line, execute

In my python file, I create an *.bmp image, which I the open to check everything went fine.

It is a bit of a hassle to open this each time I run my program (I know, I'm too lazy) and using show seems counterintuitive, since it freezes the execution and I can't keep it open.

Which is the command in python to open files?, you know like a:

```
command='gedit file.txt'
pythonmagic.execute(command)
```

Obviously pythonmagic and the syntax are the things I'm missing.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "pythonmagic" is called `subprocess`.  Search StackOverflow for anything related to [python] and "background process" and you'll find many, many copies of this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you want the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gedit', 'file.txt'])
```

The above code will open gedit with the single argument 'file.txt' (i.e. open the file in gedit).

If you add the line,

```
proc.wait()
```

then the script will wait until you close gedit, should you ever want that.